PowerApps - Office365Users.DirectReports
I'm encountering an issue with my application's Office365Users.DirectReports function. The error message states:

office365users.directreports failed: the function 'directreports' has an invalid value for parameter 'userid' - a blank value was passed to it where it was not expected. Please make sure that a valid argument is passed to the function.

To provide some context, I'm using a text field where the manager's email is entered and the Office365Users.DirectReports function should return the direct reports:
Office365Users.DirectReports(Head_Department_Name.Value)

The application runs fine, but this error appears during data loading, and I need to hide this notification.
Could anyone advise on how to prevent this error or hide the notification?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried to modify the following code but without success:
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.CreatedByUser),
   Office365Users.UserProfile(ThisItem.CreatedByUser).DisplayName
)


Your code is showing this error because while loading the app, it checks the parameter (Head_Department_Name.Value) which initially turns out to be blank. Adding just a simple check will make the error go away. Following is an example:
If(!IsBlank(Head_Department_Name.Value),
   Office365Users.DirectReports(Head_Department_Name.Value)
)

